# Website for installation information?

Tags: installation, windows-installer

Is there a website / forum dedicated to windows installation tips/information for programmers, like registry keys modified by different products (Office, SQL server, etc) at installation time? How to uninstall programmatically different packages, etc etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the best sites for all-around Windows Installer and other setup information is [AppDeploy.com](http://www.appdeploy.com/) -- there's years worth of good info there if you dig deep enough.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.superuser.com

Comment: No. I need info for programmers creating setup programs, or using .net to find if a program is installed... etc

Comment: i feel like if superuser changes, there might be bigger problems on SO than my answer here ;)